# Parse nested json from url and extract values from array using java

Tags: java, json, nested

I have a json url link which i would like to read its json response and extract values into variables so that i can use them later

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 4,
    "params": {
      "q": "*:*",
      "facet.field": "TESTARRAY",
      "indent": "true",
      "rows": "0",
      "wt": "json",
      "facet": "true"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 12,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  },
  "facet_counts": {
    "facet_queries": {},
    "facet_fields": {
      "TESTARRAY": [
        "JON",
        22,
        "SMITH",
        34,
        "ROBERT",
        12
      ]
    },
    "facet_dates": {},
    "facet_ranges": {},
    "facet_intervals": {}
  }
}
```

For extraction,I am using

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL(jsonlink), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("TEST_ARRAY");
        Integer smithage=arr.get("SMITH");
```

So far this approach is not working.
What would be the best way to deal with it
Thanks in advance

Comment: small typo problem you have this line `JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("TEST_ARRAY"); `  you dont have a "TEST_ARRAY" but a "TESTARRAY" instead.  Other than that `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);` is your answer to converting string resources to json and `Integer smithage=arr.get("SMITH");` to hold for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TEST_ARRAY` is not a top-level field, you need to dig down to get it, something like:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL(jsonlink), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
JSONObject facet_counts = obj.getJSONObjecy("facet_counts");
JSONObject facet_fields = facet_counts.getJSONObjecy("facet_fields");
JSONArray test_array = obj.getJSONArray("TESTARRAY");
Integer smithage = test_array.getInt(3);
```